# Replacing ALAssertLibrary to get the filename

Tags: ios, objective-c, alassetslibrary

Im using the following code to access filename of the image that I gotta upload. I need both filename alongside the file path and size.

```
  ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *imageAsset)
    {
        ALAssetRepresentation *imageRep = [imageAsset defaultRepresentation];
        NSLog(@"[imageRep filename] : %@", [imageRep filename]);
        [_imageNameArray addObject:[imageRep filename]];
    };

    [_uploadTbleView reloadData];
    ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [assetslibrary assetForURL:refURL resultBlock:resultblock failureBlock:nil];
```

The problem that Im facing is,

1. Xcode throws a warning message that  ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock is deprecated. How can I replace the above code to get the filename ?
2. I tried using PHAsset but every time when Im selecting the file, it  has got the same file name called `asset.jpg` for all image files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 PHAsset *asset = nil;
PHFetchOptions *fetchOptions = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:YES]];
PHFetchResult *fetchResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeImage options:fetchOptions];
if (fetchResult != nil && fetchResult.count > 0) {
    // get last photo from Photos
    asset = [fetchResult lastObject];
}

if (asset) {
    // get photo info from this asset
    PHImageRequestOptions * imageRequestOptions = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
    imageRequestOptions.synchronous = YES;
    [[PHImageManager defaultManager]
             requestImageDataForAsset:asset
                            options:imageRequestOptions
                      resultHandler:^(NSData *imageData, NSString *dataUTI,
                                      UIImageOrientation orientation, 
                                      NSDictionary *info) 
     {
          NSLog(@"info = %@", info);
          if ([info objectForKey:@"PHImageFileURLKey"]) {
               // path looks like this - 
               // file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/###APPLE/IMG_####.JPG
               NSURL *path = [info objectForKey:@"PHImageFileURLKey"];
     }                                            
    }];
}
```

Comment: asset = [fetchResult lastObject]; prints the last captured image file name I want the selected image object not the lastone

Comment: [fetchResult enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(PHAsset *asset, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"asset %@", asset);
}];

Comment: Go through the documentation it will be very helpful so you will get an good idea about PHAsset http://nshipster.com/phimagemanager/

Comment: I tried it but its not getting the name of selected file but it enumerated all files in the album and prints the corresponding names

Comment: this does indeed provide the path.. but I see issues as follows:

`Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257`
`"The file “IMG_0811.JPG” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it." UserInfo=`
`{NSURL=file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0811.JPG,`
`NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0811.JPG,`
`NSUnderlyingError=0x1744525d0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}} #Generic`
```