# How to export image to phone gallery using PHPhotoLibrary

Tags: ios, objective-c

To export image to phone gallery I tried use ALAssetsLibrary but Xcode 8.0 inform me that method is deprecated and I should use PHPhotoLibrary. When I use ALAssetsLibrary then method looks like that:

```
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>
-(void)exportToGallery{
  ALAssetsLibrary *assetsLib = [ALAssetsLibrary new];
  [assetsLib writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:image
  metadata:[image properties];
  completionBlock:nil;
}
```

How can I use PHPhotoLibrary to have the same effect?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37405691/replacing-alassertlibrary-to-get-the-filename/37405786#37405786

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save picture to iPhone photo library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178915/how-to-save-picture-to-iphone-photo-library)

Comment: No, that questions and answers are different

Comment: @kenzolek Check my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way to do that.

> **Objective C**

Import the Photos Framework

```
#import <Photos/Photos.h>
```

Then make your image

```
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DP.jpg"];
```

Then save the image. The image will be saved to **Camera Roll**.
This will work same as `writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum` of `ALAssetsLibrary`

```
[[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
        [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromImage:image];
    } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        if (success) {
            NSLog(@"Image Saved");
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"error in saving image : %@",error);
        }
    }];
```

Make sure the permission for photos is **ON**.
Also if you have created the project of Xcode 8, then you need to add a key in `Info.plist`

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Use Photos</string>
```

You can also use the `creationRequestForAssetFromImage` method not only with UIImage making but also with an image URL too.

These are the methods you can use from **Photos Framework**.

```
+ (instancetype)creationRequestForAssetFromImage:(UIImage *)image;
+ (nullable instancetype)creationRequestForAssetFromImageAtFileURL:(NSURL *)fileURL;
+ (nullable instancetype)creationRequestForAssetFromVideoAtFileURL:(NSURL *)fileURL;
```

> **Swift 3.0**

```
let image = UIImage(named: "DP.jpg")
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({ 
    PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: image!)
}) { (success:Bool, error:Error?) in
    if success {
        print("Image Saved Successfully")
    } else {
        print("Error in saving:"+error.debugDescription)
    }
}
```

The other methods for **Photos Framework** for Swift are:

```
open class func creationRequestForAsset(from image: UIImage) -> Self
open class func creationRequestForAssetFromImage(atFileURL fileURL: URL) -> Self?
open class func creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL fileURL: URL) -> Self?
```